# Javascript, string interpolated function name

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript newbie.

I have a line of code:

```
data.content_teaser.image_square_attachment_url
```

square can change: I have a variable called contentType that can be `'square'`, or `'vertical'` or `'horizontal'`.

In ruby I can use send with the string interpolation, how can I obtain the same in js?

Something like `"data.content_teaser.image_" + contentType + "_attachment_url"`

Comment: So what do you expect?

Comment: I cannot understand how can I change using the string of a var a method name...

Comment: So what are you doing that requires changing function name?

Comment: I have a variable that is a string. I need to use the string value to change the function name...

Comment: `Why` is the question? Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has 2 ways to access object properties/methods - dot-notation and square-bracket-notation. The latter uses a string what you could build up in the normal way you would for any string. So these 2 are equivalent:

```
data.content_teaser.image_square_attachment_url;
data.content_teaser["image_square_attachment_url"];
```

So, to answer your question:

```
var contentType = "square";
var result = data.content_teaser["image_" + contentType + "_attachment_url"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's string interpolation since ES2015 look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals :

```
`string text ${expression} string text`
```

So, you can use something like this :

```
let s = `image_${contentType}_attachment_url`
```

And after that :

```
data.content_teaser[s]
```